# Rails: many to many to many issue creating new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, nested-forms, has-many-through

I've got a rails app that I've been working on which has three many to many models. Basically, the app has courses which can have many locations and locations can have many instructors through `courseassociations`.

When a user creates a new course, I'd like them to add the course details, add a new or existing location and for each location assign or create a new instructor.

My app currently looks like the following;

**Models**

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courseassociations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :courseinstructors, through: :courseassociations
  has_many :courselocations, through: :courseassociations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :courselocations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :courseinstructors
end

class Courselocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courseassociations
  has_many :courseinstructors, through: :courseassociations
  has_many :courses, through: :courseassociations
end

class Courseinstructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courseassocaitions
  has_many :courses, through: :courseassocaitions
end
```

**Controller**

```
class Admin::CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @course = Course.new
    1.times {@course.courselocations.build}
    1.times {@course.courseinstructors.build}
  end
    def course_params
      params.require(:course).permit(:name, :summary, :description, :signup_link, :price, courselocations_attributes: [:id, :name, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode, :_destroy], courseinstructors_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :title, :company, :image, :_destroy, :id])

    end
end
```

**View (Nested form via Course)**

```
  <% if @course.new_record? %>
    <%= f.fields_for :courselocations do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'courselocation_fields', f: builder %>
      <%= f.fields_for :courseinstructors do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'courseinstructor_fields', f: builder %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

In my controller, having `courselocations_attributes: [...]` and `courseinstructors_attributes: [...]` returns `Unpermitted parameter: courseinstructors_attributes`

If I change the controller like so; `courselocations_attributes: [..., courseinstructors_attributes: [...]]` this works, however my `courseassociations` table looks like the following;

```
| id | course_id | courselocation_id | courseinstructor_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 |                 1 |                NULL | 2017-10-13 03:15:43 | 2017-10-13 03:15:43 |
|  2 |         2 |                 2 |                NULL | 2017-10-13 03:35:05 | 2017-10-13 03:35:05 |
|  3 |         2 |                 3 |                NULL | 2017-10-13 03:35:05 | 2017-10-13 03:35:05 |
|  4 |      NULL |                 3 |                   1 | 2017-10-13 15:33:46 | 2017-10-13 03:35:05
```

What I would expect is

```
| id | course_id | courselocation_id | courseinstructor_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 |                 1 |                NULL | 2017-10-13 03:15:43 | 2017-10-13 03:15:43 |
|  2 |         2 |                 2 |                NULL | 2017-10-13 03:35:05 | 2017-10-13 03:35:05 |
|  3 |         2 |                 3 |                   1 | 2017-10-13 03:35:05 | 2017-10-13 03:35:05 |
|  4 |         2 |                 3 |                   2 | 2017-10-13 03:35:05 | 2017-10-13 03:35:05 |
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Sample console output

```
Started POST "/admin/courses" for ::1 at 2017-10-14 23:02:48 -0400
Processing by Admin::CoursesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aXe/nmTm32mBoA50eXea8b45CXheQh22fCIqcX6mzmHqJTDBD/pbTe5ZKUavyMCyJumOVJwI5KPAKb/6J2C3dQ==", "commit"=>"Save", "course"=>{"name"=>"Test IBE Course", "summary"=>"Test IBE Course", "description"=>"<p>\r\n\tTest IBE Course\r\n</p>", "price"=>"1000.00", "signup_link"=>"Test", "courselocations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"IBE 1", "address"=>"Some road", "city"=>"Boston", "state"=>"MA", "zipcode"=>"02135", "_destroy"=>"false", "courseinstructors_attributes"=>{"1508036554699"=>{"first_name"=>"Kyla", "last_name"=>"Slen", "title"=>"VP", "company"=>"EurekaConnect", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007faf7e27c0d8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/87/27b7nz496w1dms5_my1z2mxm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20171014-43380-10zghle.jpg>, @original_filename="250px-PlagueOfInsecticons_Bumblebee_and_Spike_hide.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"course[courselocations_attributes][0][courseinstructors_attributes][1508036554699][image]\"; filename=\"250px-PlagueOfInsecticons_Bumblebee_and_Spike_hide.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "_destroy"=>"false"}}}}}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `courses` WHERE (permalink = 'test-ibe-course')
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `courselocations` WHERE (permalink = 'ibe-1-boston-ma')
  Courselocation Load (23.8ms)  SELECT `courselocations`.* FROM `courselocations` WHERE (permalink LIKE 'ibe-1-boston-ma%')  ORDER BY id
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `courseinstructors` WHERE (permalink = 'kyla-slen')
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `courses` (`name`, `summary`, `description`, `signup_link`, `price`, `permalink`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Test IBE Course', 'Test IBE Course', '<p>\r\n Test IBE Course\r\n</p>', 'Test', '1000.00', 'test-ibe-course', '2017-10-15 03:02:49', '2017-10-15 03:02:49')
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `courselocations` (`name`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zipcode`, `permalink`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('IBE 1', 'Some road', 'Boston', 'MA', '02135', 'ibe-1-boston-ma-1', '2017-10-15 03:02:49', '2017-10-15 03:02:49')
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `courseinstructors` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `title`, `company`, `image`, `permalink`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Kyla', 'Slen', 'VP', 'EurekaConnect', 'ibeinc/bc2uq6g1ttzeycbge0gc.jpg', 'kyla-slen', '2017-10-15 03:02:49', '2017-10-15 03:02:49')
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `courseinstructors` SET `courseinstructors`.`image` = 'image/upload/v1508036568/ibeinc/bc2uq6g1ttzeycbge0gc.jpg' WHERE `courseinstructors`.`id` = 2
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `courselocations` SET `name` = 'IBE 1', `address` = 'Some road', `city` = 'Boston', `state` = 'MA', `zipcode` = '02135', `permalink` = 'ibe-1-boston-ma-1', `created_at` = '2017-10-15 03:02:49', `updated_at` = '2017-10-15 03:02:49', `id` = 8 WHERE `courselocations`.`id` = 8
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `courseassociations` (`courselocation_id`, `courseinstructor_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (8, 2, '2017-10-15 03:02:50', '2017-10-15 03:02:50')
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `courses` SET `name` = 'Test IBE Course', `summary` = 'Test IBE Course', `description` = '<p>\r\n Test IBE Course\r\n</p>', `signup_link` = 'Test', `price` = '1000.00', `permalink` = 'test-ibe-course', `created_at` = '2017-10-15 03:02:49', `updated_at` = '2017-10-15 03:02:49', `id` = 7 WHERE `courses`.`id` = 7
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `courseassociations` (`course_id`, `courselocation_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (7, 8, '2017-10-15 03:02:50', '2017-10-15 03:02:50')
   (6.9ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Can you give us the console output, for when it crashes, so we can see the actual posted parameters to the controller?

Comment: Sure, I've updated above with the output for a sample where the records get inserted separately into the courseassociations table